# Evaluation of a univariate polynomial based on sum of the coefficients

Tags: polynomials

Do we have any univariate polynomial $P(X)$ with the special property that $P(s)$ for some field element $s$ can be computed based on the sum of the coefficients $c_i$'s and a function of input, say $g(s)$? for example, $P(s) = (\sum_{i=1}^n c_i) \cdot g(s)$ for some arbitrary function $g$.

Comment: Do we have any such polynomial? Yes, for example $P=0$ with $c_i=0$.

Comment: Right, but mostly interested in non-trivial cases like non-zero coefficients

Comment: Assuming $\sum_i c_i \ne 0$, how about $g(X) = P(X)/\sum_i c_i$?

Comment: yes, that's true. but I don't want the computation $P(X)$ be included in g(X) again. ...And sorry, I should have composed my question in more detail I think.